# When $y = x^3+px+q$ will will be tangent to $x$ axis.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

When $y = x^3+px+q$ will will be tangent to $x$ axis. Answer is ${(\frac{p}{3})^3}$ + ${(\frac{q}{2}})^2=0$. I am now at real analysis class and at derivatives,this is new type of problem for me can you provide help?

[image]

This I found but can't undertand from line $2 \to$ line $3$

Comment: The graph of $y=x^3+px+q$ is tangent to the $x$ axis when it has a double root. Now, this is equivalent to say that it has a root which is also a root of the derivative $(x^3+px+q)'$.

Comment: You can do it with first term calculus.  You need a double root, ie. a root shared between the cubic and its derivative.

Comment: @hardmath is right, although it could be a triple root.

Comment: This is an example of why a list of equations is often not a good enough solution - there should be some words explaining what's going on! It's also missing a key step of $y'=3x^2+p=0$.

Answer (score 1):

As @aschepler commented, there is an important information missing before  the chain of equations, which is the requirement of  $\color{green}{y'=3x^2+p=0,3x^2=-p}$. This explains the jump from (2) to (3). Step (4') replacing $3x^2$ with $-p$ added below to clarify the missing link too.

\begin{align}y = x^3+px+q \tag 1\\
\\
 x\color{green}{(\require{cancel}\bcancel{3x^2+p})}-2x^3=-q \tag 2 \\
4x^6=q^2 \tag 3\\
\frac{(3x^2)^3}{27}=\frac{q^2}{4} \tag 4\\
\frac{({\color{green}{-p}})^3}{27}=\frac{q^2}{4} \tag {4'}\\
\frac{p^3}{27}+\frac{q^2}{4}=0 \tag 5
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

$f(x) = x^3+px+q$ is tangent to the $x$-axis, when $x$-axis is tangent to $f(x)$ :)

So at the point of tangency (if there is one), we must have $f'(x)$ coincide with the slope of the $x$-axis (which is zero).

Answer (score 0):

You are right, this step is quite unclear.

What you need to do is to eliminate $x$ between the equation and that obtained by taking the derivative, to express that the root is double:

$$\begin{cases}x^3+px+q=0,\\3x^2+p=0.\end{cases}$$

Now we replace $x^2$ in the first,

$$\begin{cases}x\left(-\dfrac p3\right)+px+q=0,\\3x^2+p=0.\end{cases}$$ which gives us

$$x=-\frac{3q}{2p}$$

and finally

$$3\left(-\frac{3q}{2p}\right)^2+p=0.$$